Install packages with text file in command line Conda error: OSError [Errno 2] No such file or directory
I am trying to run a friend's code on Jupyter notebooks in a remote server, and he provided a text file with over 200 packages and the correct version numbers to install to ensure consistent output. I have tried to install the packages in my virtual environment using the following command
pip install -r packages.txt
I however constantly get the following output
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1648883617327/work (from -r packages.txt (line 21))
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1648883617327/work'
The packages.txt file is in the same directory as the code to be run to make sure it can find it, though in looking at this error it seems that the error is coming from something with conda itself. I am running this on a remote server through a VPN connection so I am not sure how to change or access this particular directory. Every solution to the problem I've seen seem to require this, but I am not sure if this is the same issue or not.
I have tried to edit my original command as I assumed there was something in the syntax or that it couldn't find packages.txt, but this seems to be a much deeper conda error.
Edit: here's an image of my packages.txt file in question. Line 21 is where the error is being thrown now:
Image of Packages.txt

I'm unsure what is going on from your description. pip and conda are two different package managers and so pip install -r packages.txt wouldn't be expected to cause that. Usually the command is pip install -r -requirements.txt if you need to look around for other examples. By the way, "text file with over 200 packages and the correct version numbers to install to ensure consistent output" sounds like nightmare. Ideally, try to determine the key ones necessary to run the code and limit things to that. ...

 And a good option to try, is to try it first with those, without the version numbers. You can always limit things to the ones that really need the old versions if that is the case. Think of that list as a guide because it can be hard to set up an environment with all those depending on how new your Python and things are vs. the age of all those packages. If they needed that exact environment, then saving a docker image would have been helpful.

So I created a virtual enviornment with conda, which is why I think I am getting a conda error. I just am not sure why I am getting it. I renamed my "packages.txt" to "requirements.txt" to try this command but that also still doesn't work. Is there anything else needed to help clarify this error?

Oh okay. Making the virtual environment to do this in with conda makes sense. But then I'm missing why pip is triggering something about conda feedstock. Is this remote server a virtual environment itself, or your access account by any chance? Then you can remove conda from this anyway. I gather it isn't the case but thought I'd verify? Or can you make a docker container inside this server where you can just work with pip install -r to install the packages in your list? Changing the name won't help, I don't think. I just thought looking for places where others did similar things ...

 would be more fruitful if you were using the more common conventions to look around. Going back to the server thing... With a simpler setup maybe on a different remote machine, such as AWS, can you get some of the packages in your packages.txt file to work? Or maybe even on this machine, if you simplify your install file does it work? Is it only some of them that cause this?

Yes, this is a remote server but the remote server is not itself a virtual environment. I had to create the virtual environment on the server itself, and this is all within my access account on the server.  I did however try what you suggested and create a smaller install file and that worked. When I went to look at the full install text file, I found what was giving it the error:    Brotli @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1648883617327/work.

This is the file path that comes up in the error so I think this and other related lines in the pre-established text file are causing this error to come up. My only issue though is my friend who gave me this code ran this code on the same server that I did, so I am not sure why it would work for him but not for me.

"so I think this and other related lines in the pre-established text file are causing this error to come up". But we cannot see those lines or something you can share that gives the same error, and so it is hard to debug given the limited information. As for it working for you friend.... Is it possible the server changed since then? Are their accounts you are using? Did they set some environmental settings you aren't? Some configuration that they forgot to note?

Yes I know you can't see those lines. When I say related lines, I mean lines in the packages file that reference the directory that shows up in the error:     /home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1648883617327/work                       There are several lines which reference this in the Packages.txt file.  I will try to get rid of them. I also just learned from my friend that this packages.txt file was obtained using a pip freeze command, so he never actually ran it but it's just feedback about what packages he had already in his virtual environment.

Yes pip freeze sounds right, and I think that point about not ever running it is important. Even without knowing that I was trying to advise in my first few comments (based on experience reviving old things in the past, or keep them going as Python, Jupyter, and dependencies change) to take that list of packages and versions as a rough guide and not specifics to try to move towards getting something working with Python and Jupyter and the packages of today. Like I said, a Docker image/container would have been nice, but maybe it is overkill here. Hard to tell much without seeing.

And just for clarification, yes my friend was running on the same server, but in his own virtual environment. Ideally, I was hoping that installing this "packages.txt" file into my newly created virtual environment would give me access to the same packages and package versions that he had and thus give me the same output.

Yeah, sorry, I wasn't quite sure how to attach an image of the packages.txt file as it was so large and didn't know if a snippet would help. I just edited my question to include an image of the first 30 lines, as line 21 is where the first error occurs. Kind of late now and I think you gave me an idea where to go with it, but thought you might want to see what I have been talking about

Pretty much on forums such as here and Jupyter Community Discource, you shouldn't be attaching things that are text or code as images. Screenshots are only good if you are trying to show a behavior that is hard to fully describe and even then you should do both because text searching cannot index images and so you thread becomes a silo that isn't consistent with how StackOverflow and forums like that are meant to work. Read How do I ask a good question?, paying particular attention to the section entitled 'Help others reproduce the problem'. For...

 things that are long, you can use a code snippet sharing service or GitHub's gist service to share the code/text. (Although looking at your screenshot, if that is the extent of it, you can easily share that here.) When sharing code you can use markdown formatting to signal to StackOverflow that is code or computational history, see where it says 'Use fenced code blocks by surrounding your code with....' here for the best, easiest way.

So, yes now I see you have Brotli @ file:///home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/brotli-split_1648883617327/work as a line in your text file and it causes the error. Just try replacing that with Brotli, according to here. Or intstall that with conda and point at your conda feedstock_root directory similar to there. I'm not sure which is better because I'm not familiar with trying to do it this way. For what I am seeing with those cases (next would be https://pypi.org/project/cffi/), it just looks like you should first try and remove everything ...

 the first work from each of those lines that have that. I'd also suggest deleting the version numbers. And I'd even suggest deleting the entire thing and add them in one by one when you run the code and it tries to import the corresponding package, unless you know a lot of them are in there form the outset.
